# Interact with Executed binary in Android

Tags: android, binaryfiles

I'm trying to Execute an interactive binary file on my android tablet.

I can execute the server binary just fine and its working perfectly.

But I need to interact with it on a CLI at a specified port where I need to send it a command and receive the response, process the response and send another command as reply.

eg:

```
$nc 192.168.1.1 8111
>Connected to CLI
$Request Server Status
>Server Sending File to Client X
$Stop Server
>Server Stopped
```

Where $command represents commands I sent and >command is the reply from server.

So to test this I tried the below function :-

```
   private String TryExecuteCommand(String command) {
    try {
        proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("nc 127.0.0.1 8888");

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        int read;
        char[] buffer1 = new char[4096];
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        DataOutputStream writer = new DataOutputStream(proc.getOutputStream());

        writer.writeBytes("continuous responses" + "\n");

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        writer.writeBytes("quit" + "\n");

        while ((read = reader.read(buffer1)) > 0)
            output.append(buffer1, 0, read);

        proc.waitFor();
        reader.close();         

        if (dataLines.length > 0)
            return dataLines.toString();
        else
            return "";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Error occured";
    }
```

With this code I'm able to get the output after the "**quit**" command is issued. But if i try to read the response before quit is issued I get the EPIPE broken error.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Any particular reason why you're not using java `Socket`s to connect to your daemon? Executing a binary is much more error prone IMHO than doing things programatically.

Comment: yea this binary is more or less like a server service . . it will receive data from a chip in the tablet and will output responses which my app has to process and in turn send responses back to the binary

Comment: I get that, but why the hassle using `nc`? You could just create a java `Socket` instance that connects to `localhost:8888`, and use *that* to send/receive commands.

Comment: oh . . ok . . .ill give that a go . . . but in the meantime I really do want to figure out how to maintain an interactive session with a binary like the Terminal manager app does.